# DBpedia Information Extraction Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, extract, text-extraction, information-extraction

Has anyone ever used the Wikipedia Data Extraction? I need to use it for work.

Could you give other tools for extracting information on web pages?

Thanks!

Comment: This is more a forum kind of question. I think this is not the right place to discuss such a broad subject. Maybe you would benefit from narrowing the question a little bit! Bye!

Answer (score 4):

When you say Wikipedia Data Extraction, I assume you're referring to the [software](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbpedia/develop) DBpedia uses to transform Wikipedia XML dumps into the [DBpedia data dumps](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads351)?  Have you considered using the DBpedia dumps themselves?

Tools to extract information from web pages is a very broad space.  What kind of information do you want to extract?  Is it from semi-structured (e.g. tables), or unstructured text (e.g. prose).  Are you interested in metadata such as page title and author, or lower-level concepts such as named entities?

(I would have left these clarifying questions on the question but my account level doesn't allow it)